# Why are all the events filtered out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

Am making an event filter using the following data. However it seems all the event got filtered out.
I am not sure what is wrong though

```js
[
  {
    index: 1,
    eventname: "Swimming",
    price: [250, 100, 350],
    date: [20230812, 20230831],
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    eventname: "Fencing",
    price: [220, 140, 50],
    date: [20230712, 20230913],
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    eventname: "Jogging",
    price: [90, 70, 50],
    date: [20230308, 20230609],
  },
  {
    index: 4,
    eventname: "Basketball",
    price: [160, 140, 120],
    date: [20230911, 20230221],
  },
];
```

The Event Filters are as follows:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { HiOutlineMagnifyingGlass } from "react-icons/hi2";
import "./eventmain.css";
import "../App.css";

const EventNameFilter = ({ onInputChange }) => {
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    onInputChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="event-name-filter">
      <label htmlFor="eventname">Event name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="event-name-search"
        placeholder="Enter event name"
        className="event-name"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const PriceSlider = ({ onPriceChange }) => {
  const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    onPriceChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="price-slider">
      <label htmlFor="pricerange" className="flex flex-col">
        Price Range{" "}
      </label>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="500"
        id="pricerange"
        onInput={handlePriceChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const GoToLocation = () => {
  return <div className="go-to-location"> Find by location</div>;
};

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <HiOutlineMagnifyingGlass />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function EventFilterBar() {
  return (
    <div className="event-filter-bar">
      <EventNameFilter />
      <PriceSlider />
      <GoToLocation />
      <Search />
      <div>
        <p id="username">Username</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img
          id="usericon"
          src="./free-user-icon-3296-thumb.png"
          alt="user icon"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the event page

```jsx
export default function EventMain() {
  const [searchInput, setInput] = useState("");
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(750);

  const handleSearchInput = (value) => {
    setInput(value);
  };

  const handlePriceChange = (value) => {
    setMaxPrice(value);
  };

  const getEarliestDate = (dates) => {
    return Math.min(...dates);
  };

  const getLatestDate = (dates) => {
    return Math.max(...dates);
  };

  const filteredEvents = mockEventData
    .filter((event) =>
      event.eventname.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()),
    )
    .filter((event) => Math.max(event.price) < maxPrice);

  return (
    <div className="event-main">
      <EventFilterBar
        onInputChange={handleSearchInput}
        onPriceChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <HeaderBar />
      {filteredEvents.map((event, index) => (
        <EventCard
          key={index}
          eventname={event.eventname}
          earliestdate={getEarliestDate(event.date)}
          latestdate={getLatestDate(event.date)}
          price={event.price.toSorted((a, b) => a - b).toString()}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The event cards

```jsx
import "./eventmain.css";
import { IoIosStar, IoIosStarOutline } from "react-icons/io";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function EventCard({
  eventname,
  earliestdate,
  latestdate,
  price,
}) {
  const [starred, setStarred] = useState(false);

  const StarIcon = starred ? (
    <IoIosStar onClick={() => setStarred(!starred)} />
  ) : (
    <IoIosStarOutline onClick={() => setStarred(!starred)} />
  );

  return (
    <div className="event-card">
      <div className="event-element">
        <p>{eventname}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="event-element">
        <p>{earliestdate}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="event-element">
        <p>{latestdate}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="event-element">
        <p>{price}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="event-element">{StarIcon}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Make sure you read the documentation for [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and understand the format of its parameters